# "The system is running in low graphics mode", unable to connect to the Internet

Tags: 12.04, internet-connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

When I try to log onto Ubuntu, I get a notice that reads:

> **The system is running in low graphics mode.**

I searched for a solution and there are a slew of answers. However, many of them seem to suggest reinstalling different things.

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and getting to a terminal, I attempt commands like `sudo apt-get install example`. Upon doing so I get notices that say things such as `could not resolve host` which I am assuming means I'm not connected to the Internet. Since I can not connect to the Internet, none of these responses are helpful to me.

What can I do?

Comment: Please update your question with additional data as per this instruction: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/

Comment: These are 2 separate questions ;)